# for-each-group text paragraph - xslt 2.0

Tags: html, xml, xslt, xslt-2.0

I am looking for a solution to group text based on the title h1. I tried this with for-each-group, starts-with ="h1". The problem is that the h1 is not on the same level as the rest of the elements (div/h1).

Input html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html SYSTEM "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html>
<head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>test</title>   
</head>
<body>
<div>
    <h1><b>TRAIN</b></h1>
</div>
<p>text</p>
<p>In this field there is text</p>
<div>
    <h1><b>nr1</b><b>CAR</b></h1>
</div>
<h2><b>1.</b><b>nr2</b><b>area</b></h2>
<p>infos about cars</p>
<p><b>more and</b>more infos about cars</p>
</body>
</html>
```

What I have so far is:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0" 
xpath-default-namespace="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" method="xhtml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"
 indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="head"/>

<xsl:template match="body">

    <xsl:for-each-group select = "*" group-starting-with = "h1">
        <output>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()"/>
        </output>
    </xsl:for-each-group>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="*">
    <xsl:element name="{name()}">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

But the output is not working the way I want. I would like to have two output-blocks as this example output:

```
<html>
<output>
  <div><h1><b>TRAIN</b></h1></div>
  <p>text</p>
  <p>In this field there is text</p>
</output>

<output>
  <div><h1><b>nr1</b><b>CAR</b></h1></div>
  <h2>
     <b>1.</b>
     <b>nr2</b>
     <b>area</b>
  </h2>
  <p>infos about cars</p>
  <p><b>more and</b>more infos about cars</p>
</output>
```

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the `descendant-or-self` axis, to group starting on elements which have `h1` as a descendant (or are `h1` elements themselves)

```
<xsl:for-each-group select="*" group-starting-with="*[descendant-or-self::h1]">
```

Also note that in your XSLT you have used `xpath-default-namespace`, but your input XML does not use that namespace, so as it stands your `body` template in your XSLT won't match the input. Either you need to add the default namespace to your input, or remove the `xpath-default-namespace` from your XSLT.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I was struggling with the axes. This is the sollution. And thanks for the extra note.

Answer (score 1):

How about:

**XSLT 2.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/html">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:for-each-group select="body/*" group-starting-with="div[h1]">
            <output>
                <xsl:copy-of select="current-group()"/>
            </output>
        </xsl:for-each-group>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```